# Is [graph] an appropriate Stack Overflow tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

"Graph" probably means different things in different Stack Exchange sites.

The Graph tag on Stack Overflow site is looks like a disorganized combination of:

- Graph as in chart
- Graph as in graph db (e.g. triplestores)
- Graph as in collection of node-edge combinations
- [meanings in Stack Overflow wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/graph/info)

Should items be re-tagged or should we just do away with the ambiguous "Graph" tag?

There are tags for [triplestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triplestore) and [graph-databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-databases) perhaps anything tagged [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph) and [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) should get a [graph-databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-databases) tag and drop the ambiguous [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph).

Comment: This tag is [graph]ically ambiguous.

Comment: As a stop-gap measure to prevent misuse, the tag [tag:graph] has been synonymised with [tag:charts]. All incorrect uses of this tag should be dealt on ad-hoc basis. These tags will NOT be merged so if in the future someone decides to perform proper burnination, we can desonynimise to make it easier.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for helping with this. Unfortunately you can still select “graph” as a tag, which folks can and will select when they have a question about graph algorithms. When you type “graph” in the tag box, you’ll see the “graph” tag, as well as other tags related to graphics (“3d”?!), but not “graph-theory” nor “graph-algorithm”; you have to know it exists to find it. I think this is a bug in the design of the tag search algorithm, but we won’t be able to do anything about that…

Comment: @Dharman I'm not sure how this prevents misuse. If anything, the synonym has put a clearly wrong tag on tens of thousands of posts that previously had a merely ambiguous tag.

Comment: @bergi The tag was not ambiguous. It had exactly the same description as the other one. If someone tries using it, they are more likely to notice they used an incorrect tag.

Comment: @Dharman Not a few days ago, when the descripton was about the data structure (but the tag had been misused often). I can't see the history unfortunately now that it's been synonymised.

Comment: @Bergi The description was not about data structures. You can see this here https://web.archive.org/web/20230930201641/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph You are probably thinking of [tag:graph-theory] which still exists as a separate tag. That's what I am talking about: people confused the two tags too often. At least now it should be plenty clear what is what.

Comment: @Dharman I fail to see how things are clearer now. If you’re writing a question, and you select “graph” for the tag, you still see “graph” for the tag, just like it was before. People still don’t read the tag description, and people still don’t see “graph-theory” appear when they type “graph” in the tag box.  Nothing has changed other than that you now get to see all the “chart” questions when you search for “graph” questions.

Comment: @CrisLuengo But that's the point. I know it's not a good solution, but in the absence of any other solution, this seems like the best we can do. People who search for "chart" should see questions from both "chart" and "graph" as they are the same thing. Or at least according to the tag description they were the same thing. If someone accidently adds "graph" tag to non-chart question it will be automatically converted to "chart" and easier to spot the mistake.

Comment: @Dharman But that's just what I'm saying: it's not automatically converted. If you tag "graph", you see the "graph" tag, and the asker is none the wiser.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It is converted once you press Save button

Answer (score 8):

There are already more specific tags for these various meanings:

- [graph-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) for the data structure (nodes and edges), and the related [graph-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithm) (I suspect these should be synonyms).
- [plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plot) (and [graphing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphing), a potential synonym) for plotting a mathematical function.
- [charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charts).
- [graph-databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-databases) for the database meaning.

I think it's “only” a matter of retagging the 4400 or so questions tagged [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph).

Comment: @AndreSilva [tag:plot] is typically used for a graphical representation of a function x → y. [tag:charts] is typically used for a visual representation of discrete data (pie charts, etc.). I don't think they're used interchangeably on SO.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If all those different meanings appear on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/graph/info when should this tag actually be used? I mean, what is the appropriate use case for this tag? And if you tell me any particular use case, wouldn't that imply that this info should be edited and a disclaimer put in there when to *not* use this tag and point towards the correct alternatives?

Comment: Some time has passed. It is even more evident now that both 'plot', 'chart' and 'graph' are also used for data visualization. Your answer does not address this.

Comment: @AndreSilva that's seems like evidence that the tags shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

The [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph) tag is being used for both [plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plot)/[chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart) and [graph-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory). It is an ambiguous tag, and should be burninated.

Looking at the [newest posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph?sort=newest) it is clear that both uses are equally common, meaning that half the posts tagged with [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph) are tagged wrongly (according to the tag wiki).

There are currently more than 25000 posts with this tag, posted at a rate of about 10 per day.

When typing "graph" in the tag edit box, [graph-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) is not visible. If you don't know that this tag exists, you won't find it. I've shortened the excerpt for [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph) so that you can see  the recommendation to use [graph-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory), hopefully this aids discoverability. But we all know that most don't read the excerpts anyway...

Given that there already exist more specific tags for all concepts covered by all concepts associated to the name "graph", I suggest we just remove this tag, replacing it with more appropriate tags everywhere it is used.

Answer (score -1):

The tag does looks like it's encapsulating too much.  I took a quick look around to see what other tags handle these aspects of this tag.

- For the "chart" aspect, we have tags such as [bar-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bar-graph) and [diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diagram) handling that.  In the whole data representation aspect, we have the [data-representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-representation) tag, but it doesn't get much use - perhaps its usage should be promoted in this case?
- For the [database aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database), which I'd have to admit is pretty interesting, perhaps specific tags relating to specific APIs would be a better fit.  A quick look doesn't find any in use, though.
- For the data structure, [data-structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-structures) seems more than sufficient to cover questions about it.

I'm only throwing this out there, but perhaps [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph) be made a synonym of [data-structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-structures), and questions that deal with data representation be retagged as such.

Comment: The [plot] tag is probably a better substitute for the "chart" sense of graph tag.

Comment: No, [tag:graph] as applies to data structures is far more specific than [tag:data-structures], they are not synonyms.

Comment: Yeah, honestly data-structures itself seems way too vague to be useful.

Answer (score -2):

This is a proposal for addressing the subset of [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph) relating to charts and plots.

[chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart) and [plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plot) are being used interchangeably in most cases. Their excerpt say:

charts':

> Charts are a graphical representation of data, most often in the format of a graph or diagram. There are dozens of charting solutions available for creating charts, typically using some charting libraries (written in JavaScript or PHP) as a charting engine. Use this tag for questions about using any of the charting solutions.

plot's:

> A graphical technique for presenting a data set or an equation.

These are not ambiguous tags as [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph). Therefore, I suggest making 'plot' (x 11,601) a synonym of 'charts' (x 10781). It could be the opposite too, i.e., making 'plot' the master.

Meanwhile, we would stop [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph) being used under the concept of charts/plots. Part of graph's excerpt would say:

> Do not use this tag under the concept of charts/plots; use the charts tag instead.

Better would be to alter the entire excerpt of 'graph' saying it is an obsolete tag and pointing to the more specific tags cited by Gilles.

This will help organize upcoming questions, making it easy to organize backwards (if necessary).

Comment: The chart/plot thing seems like a distinct request, so it would be better suited in its own question - it's not going to get too much attention in an answer. Side note - we don't generally edit excerpts saying tags are obsolete, we just retag the questions with that tag and then the tag disappears (these are called [meta-tag:burninate-request]s).

Comment: @Dukeling, I agree that asking for synonymizing chart/plot could fit better as a different request. However, the proposal also aims to unlink chart/plot from 'graph'. What if I delete this answer; and ask a different question proposing chart/plot to be synonyms and proposing and edit to graph's excerpt like the one written above: _Do not use this tag.....; use charts tag instead_. Maybe I should open that new post linking this one (I mean, linking the question, not my deleted answer). What do you think?. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Sounds good, although I'd probably just link this as a footnote or a comment. This seem to already adequately address everything that needs to be done with [tag:graph] - no need to go into specifics again there. Note that the upvoted answer here specifically separates the two - if you want, you could, prior to posting your new question, ask that user the reason for this and whether those aren't essentially the same thing, or simply post a comment on that answer linking to your new question.

Comment: I don't see [tag:plot] and [tag:charts] used interchangeable: [tag:plot] is mostly about plotting functions (y as a function of x), [tag:charts] is mostly about a visual representation of discrete data. At least that's how I understand the words, and how the first page of both tags looks like. Is there a lot of use with different meanings?

Comment: [Plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plot+r) has been largely used together with 'R' (and other statistical software) to refer to charts (plot, graph) (both for discrete and continuous data visualization). Maybe 'plot' meaning plotting functions is a useless usage. @Gilles

Comment: @Dukeling, Andre - I'd like to get your opinions on [this tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5167472/8) removing the discrete math/data structure usage of the [tag:graph] tag. I'm tempted to open a new question for discussion to determine if the edit was appropriate.

Comment: @beaker I'm not entirely against it, since [tag:graph] currently has multiple meanings covered by other less ambiguous tags and should be removed (it makes sense for the wiki and excerpt to reflect that). I'm going to (partially) disagree with @ Dukeling and say an appropriate excerpt edit would be to say something like "DO NOT USE: This tag is ambiguous. Use ... instead." until retagging is finished, because manually retagging 17k questions is a lot of work (but I wouldn't expect that edit to necessarily get through review) You can post a question if you'd like other opinions.