# Why is Cytoscape on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, outsourcing

Why is [Cytoscape](https://cytoscape.org/index.html) on topic? The main tag [cytoscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cytoscape) says:

> Cytoscape is an open-source software platform for visualizing complex networks and integrating these with any type of attribute data. Various apps are available for different problem domains, including bioinformatics, social network analysis, and semantic web.

From a cursory scan of their site, there is nothing directly related to code or programming. It seems to be a tool to generate graphs. They also seem to [outsource their support](https://cytoscape.org/documentation_users.html):

> Search and ask questions about software installation, operation and troubleshooting. Be sure to tag your question with "cytoscape" so we can find it!

Here are a few curious questions from the recent list:

- [How to select connected components in Cytoscape v 3.8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340079/how-to-select-connected-components-in-cytoscape-v-3-8-0)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377444/issue-with-largeish-networks-in-cytoscape-3-8-0
- [How do I get functioning edge tooltips in the Cytoscape 3.8 desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321041/how-do-i-get-functioning-edge-tooltips-in-the-cytoscape-3-8-desktop-application)

I do see a [cytoscape.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cytoscape.js) and I would say ***that*** is on topic.

Comment: Why is rotation on topic? Why is Windows on topic? Or linux? Statistics? If they don't offer some kind of product you can develop software of, they have no relationship with us. Is like creating the [tripadvisor] tag for scrapping TripAdvisor ([an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62051978/792066))

Comment: I'm missing something like "GENERAL CYTOSCAPE SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. .... Note that this is for programming questions specific to Citoscape..." in the tag description. (like you can find for example in the [Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ubuntu/info) tag)

Comment: You're missing screaming case in the tag wiki that it is proven nobody reads anyway? Well, OK. Add it in if it helps you. Stack Overflow is a programming site; all tags here are assumed to be in the context of programming.

Comment: at least you can refer to it if some argues everything about citoscape is on topic just because the tag exists. And of course I know, nobody reads it...

Comment: Indeed it seems to be only some sort of support tag, but it's an edge case. You can interfere with the tool in certain ways (including code), it can be customized/configured in different ways using JSON, so, I guess, I am with @Braiam.

Comment: For what it's worth, the broader subject of [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) and edge graphs, [tag:directed-graphs], etc. are common subjects on Stack Overflow. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272033/is-graph-an-appropriate-so-tag https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393812/plotting-the-relationship-between-graph-charts-plot-and-data-visualizat

Comment: Let it burn! But keep [tag:cytoscape.js]

Comment: I don't think this should be burninated. It has a JS API, an R package, and one could develop their own way to program with Cytoscape (it's open source). Seems enough of a reason to have a single tag experts could follow that have a broad understanding of Cytoscape internals/programming with it.

Comment: "open-source software platform" makes it on-topic. Software developers use "software platforms" to write software for end users. Perhaps I want to embed that platform in a novel application. Should I have to write my own graphing library to have an on topic question? And who's going to read my graphing library implementation to answer my question?

Comment: [tag:cytoscape] is a multi-repository project; [tag:cytoscape.js]  is one of the component repositories, as seen [here](https://github.com/cytoscape).

Answer (score 9):

Cyotscape has multiple programming interfaces.

- Python: [py2cytoscape](https://py2cytoscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/https://py2cytoscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- R: [RCy3](https://github.com/cytoscape/RCy3)
- JavaScript: [cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/)
- HTTP: [CyREST](http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Programmatic_Access_to_Cytoscape_Features_Scripting.html#cyrest-interface-layer)
- Custom scripting language: [Cytoscape commands](http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Programmatic_Access_to_Cytoscape_Features_Scripting.html#commands)

Cytoscape specifically [recommends](http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Programmatic_Access_to_Cytoscape_Features_Scripting.html) these interfaces in their documentation.

This means that it serves as a programming platform, able to be integrated with other programming tools. Deeming the tool as a whole off topic would be wrong, but SO shouldn't support users just working with its GUI. Things like installation are somewhat gray areas, since those may affect programmers trying to write code against the tool, but questions and answers should be geared towards programmers rather than general usage if there's any differences.